# I am trying to multiply 2 specific numbers, when there is text in a cell many times in a row, ending by add all products together

Tags: worksheet-function

For Example: Row 3:  Because there is a date in B3 it needs to Multiply B2 and A3, then Multiply D3 and D2, then J2 and A3.  Then adding all those products and giving a total in cell K3.  Doing this for each row.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT with BOOLEANs

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A3*$B$2:$J$2*($B3:$J3<>""))
```

Now when `$B3:$J3` is empty it will return `0` to the SUMPRODUCT, Otherwise it will multiply the value in row 2 with column A.

Comment: THIS WORKED THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @SegerFarms please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B3:J3)),$B$2:$J$2*$A3))` (insert in K3)

---

If this solution answers your problem, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: A couple of caveats with this approach.  If the data in B:J are filled via a formula that returns `""` when needed, ISBLANK will return FALSE for all cells.  And, it is worth noting that if the user is using something older than office 365, versions without dynamic arrays, this will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when confirming the formula.